# Skipping an article for a stronger "punch" in a headline --- incorrect or not?

Tags: articles, headline-english

I would like to skip an article in a headline I wrote. It feels right to skip it, the sentence sounds stronger in my opinion. However, all the spelling checkers tell me it's bad English.

Can the "a" be skipped below in a context of a headline or is it straight up a primary school silly mistake?

> We do this through digital strategy designed specifically for you.

vs

> We do this through **a** digital strategy designed specifically for you.

Note: Let me add that there's no "a" specific strategy. The idea to convey here is that the tool of digital strategy is used by us.

Comment: As you say, _a strategy_ is a specific plan -  _strategy_ without an article is the skill or practice of making plans.

Comment: What is "puch"? Or is it a typo in your question title?

Comment: @Conrado Haha, it should have been a "punch". Fixed.

Comment: This doesn't look like a [headline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline) - a headline is normally a cluster of words at the top of a news story, typically describing an event, designed as a stand-alone text, and written with a distinctive [syntax and vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese). Use of the pronoun "this" strongly suggests your sentence follows other text and hence is not a headline. It would help if you explain what you are writing. Is this intended as some kind of advertising copy or tag line at the end of an advertisement?

Comment: @StuartF Yes, it's a part of a headline in a website's copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Strategy" may be used as either a countable or an uncountable noun with similar but slightly different connotations. The use of the article indicates the countable usage, which indicates a specific plan. The lack of the article indicates the uncountable usage, which more refers to the process of implementing the plan.
Consider a couple of examples:

> We should try different marketing strategies.

This refers to specific plans that can be enumerated.

> Marketing strategy is an important consideration in launching a new
> product.

This refers to the general process or skill of planning, but does not refer a specific plan.

The countable case with the article sounds much more natural to me.  I would expect that someone would design *a specific* strategy for me, I have a hard time conceptualizing how someone would design the general concept of (uncountable) strategy for me.

Comment: Yes, eventually I came to the same conclusion: that the act of "designing it" specifically for someone implies it's in fact a specific plan. Thank you for confirming it!